# Hashing + security as it pertains to a theoretical file sharing site

Tags: security, theory, hashing

These days it's possible to hash a file client-side, send the hash to the server, and have the server check whether or not that file is already uploaded. If it is, we can skip the file upload and make it appear to upload almost instantly to the user. This can also save have oodles of bandwidth for a large site.

This has some important security implications, however.

1. If the user is clever, he can use this information to determine what files are already on the server, including illegal or sensitive documents
2. He can produce millions of fake hashes, send them to the server, and hope for a collision to gain access to random documents
3. There is a legitimate but unintentional collision where the hashes are the same, but the file is actually different

My question is: is it worth the trade-off? Can we mitigate some or all of these problems? How?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sure, if you suspect that a certain illicit file is on the server you can upload another copy and deduce that it is there. But deducing isn't proof in a court of law; you'd still have to get the repo owner subpoenaed  to disclose which documents are or aren't on their systems, otherwise you may or may not convince a court that they really do have that file. And you yourself deliberately uploading the same file might weaken your own case - if you willingly put it onto an internet storage service, how secret or valuable can it be?
2. Since the hashes are used only internally by the storage provider, I don't see how a user *sending* hash values could compromise or, indeed, achieve anything.
3. The popular hash functions are good enough that this isn't a concern. Many of them are broken with respect to an intelligent, capable attacker who actively *tries* to generate hash collisions, e.g. to conduct a birthday attack. But two files that different people generate and upload are still extremely unlikely to clash - unlikely as in "you should worry about a meteor hitting the data center instead".

Comment: 2 -- in the scenario I'm envisioning, the user pretends he's uploading a file by sending all the correct get/post requests and in it he sends the fake hash. The server responds by saying "Yes! I've already got that file, you don't need to upload it!". And in doing so, it gives him privileges to that file because it thinks he already has a copy of it, at which point he can actually download it and get a copy of it.

Comment: Oh, you *do* send the hash first and then the file only if there isn't a match? Right, then this is a vulnerability. You could try to wrap the process into a proprietary client program that obfuscates the logic so that a user can't manipulate it, but that's a losing battle. The usual way to prevent such mass harvesting is to double the waiting period after each failed upload.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad approach.  And I believe its how Dropbox got busted a while back.

The approach would work if:

- The files are unencrypted on the server and you simply copy the file over without an upload (meaning anyone can see their contents)
- You use a shared encryption key for all files and you simply copy the files over without an upload (meaning you can see the contents)
- You store encryption keys on the server to allow you to decrypt and re-encrypt the files when doing such a copy (meaning you can see the contents).

Each of those options, IMO, are a serious privacy issue.  If you want it to be secure and private, you'll want a way to derive a per user key that you do not store and/or do the encryption on the client side.

Comment: Good points. It might still help prevent the same user from re-uploading the same file more than once; I know I have plenty of dupes on my machine.

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  You might also hash chunks of files, thereby allowing parts of files to match.  I believe that's what bittorrent does.

Comment: When would you ever get a partial file match? Images and video are usually different all over, and even if they're not, the encoding would throw it all off. Maybe text files, but they're small enough to hardly benefit from hashing at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be more helpful when updating a file that had changed than it would be for new files.